# Text invisible after setting Template in WPF TextBox Style

Tags: wpf

I Have a WPF Text Box , that works Normal when I override its Template directly in the window or user Control, but when I use a Style for it in a resource dictionary all properties work fine but when I set the template in the style , the text becomes invisible.

Here is the Style

```
<Style x:Key="InputTextBoxes" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource foregroundcolor1}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource foregroundcolor3}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>

<!-- Here Comes the Issue-->

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="9" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the Implementation of the style in the Text box

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" 
         Grid.Column="1"
         Name="RevokeUserNameBox"
         Margin="6"
         Style="{StaticResource InputTextBoxes}"
         Text="{Binding RevokeAdminModel.UserName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I tried adding `ContentPresenter` and removing it, but still no success.
I even had some time chatting with ChatGPT with no Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some Search I found This Answer on another Question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63362942/13176802

The Trick was that I must set

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
```

Inside the Border , as this is what is responsible for showing the text, as I understood from this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

the Final Style should be like this

```
<Style x:Key="InputTextBoxes" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource foregroundcolor1}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource foregroundcolor3}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="9" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

I hope this can help somebody in the future.